# Is there a problem with this approach to handling invalid web probes?

Tags: web-application, error-handling

Like any other website owner, I get frequent probes for vulnerabilities e.g. `.php` `.sql` or `.gz` pages.

These used to appear in my log files as 404 responses (we host on ASP.NET Core). These also take up server time and processing as it has to

1. handle the request in the pipeline
2. check the static files for a match
3. check the routing table for a match
4. redirecting to the error handler middleware
5. log the error
6. show the 404 error page

Using postman I see that a generic 404 returns about 5.44kb in HTML

So I've added a middleware handler for requests that checks for requests ending in suspect extensions such as these, which just clears the response with no further processing. This response is now 129 bytes but returns a 200.

My question therefore - Is this a safe approach? I can change the response to 404, although I doubt they'd think the blank response a valid one.

Comment: How do you define "safe"? What's your goal? "I doubt they'd think the blank response a valid one" -- what's your basis for this conclusion? Who is "they"? Have you looked at vulnerability scanners to see what approaches they use?

Comment: All good points, thanks @schroeder. I guess when they scan they are looking for 200 responses which would indicate a good target to probe further - which I don't want. If they get the 404 response then they can cross my host off their target list as it's not vulnerable/compatible. So I've changed to a 404 response - but still no further processing.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to care about if the status you return is the most appropriate. It's a scan anyway, and if your code returns a blank page with HTTP 200 status and the scanner segfaults and catches fire, it's not your problem. You must care about legitimate requests, not much about non-legitimate ones.

On my lab servers (online with public IP) I use fail2ban: 4 HTTP 4xx errors bans the IP for an hour. On some places I use a [tarpit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) just for fun, such as [LaBrea PHP Tarpit](https://github.com/msigley/PHP-HTTP-Tarpit).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, we're ASP.NET Core so can't use any PHP related stuff.

Comment: You can port it to ASP.NET. It's just a couple HTTP headers and random data being sent back anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Windows server you'll have to find suitable software for the job but here is an idea.

I manage a number of Linux servers and Fail2Ban is often used to thwart **brute-force attacks** (SSH/POP/SMTP etc). There are alternatives (I personally prefer CSF-LFD). 
These tools act by watching the log files continuously and block IP addresses at **firewall** level (iptables or other). This is very effective and relieves your server that would otherwise have to handle hundreds of bad requests for nothing.

What I have done is add custom rules so that if an IP address generates too many 401/403/404 HTTP errors over a certain period of time, then I block it.

Of course there are solutions, you can have fun with <s>hackers</s> script kiddies and frustrate their efforts by returning bogus statuses. But blocking them is easier.

I don't know what kind of Fail2Ban-like solutions are available for Windows, you have to research the market. But I think this should be the job of an IDS, there should be something more comprehensive in place than just blocking these specific 'attacks'.

Comment: I had considered IP banning but I rarely get sustained attacks from a single IP. I could add a monitor of how many blocked calls by IP to check. But thanks for the suggestions

Comment: The tools that I am talking about ban the IP addresses automatically. And they unban them after a while too (otherwise your firewall rules would fill up quickly). By default I think CSF+LFD maintains 200 active IP address bans. As more addresses are being added, the previous bans are lifted so that the list of active bans remains manageable. Since you're on Windows you have fewer options but if you're looking for an open-source/non commercial tool [IPBan](https://ipban.com/) may be worth a try. I found this while searching for alternatives so this is not a recommendation but a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah Troy Hunt did something similar with HaveIBeenPwned. He hosts on CloudFlare and they have an API to add blocked IPs which is cool - that way it's not my problem to deal with.